# Multicasting message from Android app to local server

Tags: java, android, sockets, multicast

I'm developing an Android app that at some points, sends a multicast message. I'm running this on an emulator device so far.

On the same machine, I have a server (not Android, a plain Java app) that is expecting the multicast message, but it never gets it. When I start the server, since it is on my local machine, I start it the loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`). I must say that I've done this with regular Java apps and it works perfectly.

Here's the code for the Android App:

```
try {
    InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_HOST);
    byte[] data = DISCOVER_MESSAGE.getBytes();
    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
    ds.setSoTimeout(60000);
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, group, TcpipSIBDiscoverer.PORT);

    ds.send(dp);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    ds.receive(dp);
    if (dp.getLength() > 0) {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[dp.getLength()];
        System.arraycopy(dp.getData(), 0, tmp, 0, tmp.length);
        String received = new String(tmp);
        Logger.debug(this, "Received from SIB: " + received);
        SIBDescriptor sibDescriptor = createSIBDescriptor(received);

        this.discoveryListener.connectorSIBDiscovered(sibDescriptor);
    }
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    Logger.error("Socket time excedeed while waiting a response when discovering SIBs. Trying again");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.error("There was some kind of IO error while waiting for a response when discovering SIBs. Trying again");
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a regular `DatagramSocket` instead of `MulticastSocket`. This works in plain Java apps, since the listening server address is `235.0.0.1:5555`.

Not really sure if the code is not working or I have to do something in the emulator device so it can truly reach my loopback interface... Any ideas?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: I just read this: "Depending on the environment, the emulator may not be able to support other protocols (such as ICMP, used for "ping") might not be supported. Currently, the emulator does not support IGMP or multicast. " in http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#connecting. So I guess I'm forced to use a real device for this to work...

Comment: I'd checked that this code works straight away on a real device, so it is just the emulated devices that do not support multicast messages, as least, not yet...

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 on android refers to the device's localhost (or the emulators).
To reach localhost of your 'local machine' you should use 10.0.2.2.

This is discussed in a lot of topics.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but does not work when using multicast anyway, I already tried that before asking :)